# How to redirect to another page after 3 minutes and 49 seconds

Tags: php, datetime, time, redirect

I was working on a site which plays songs using soundcloud API; what I thought is why not create a loop so that songs keep playing without bothering the user, to select different song after every song. For this what I am doing is redirect the user to page of another song once the current song completes. Soundcloud API provide me the duration of currently playing song in a PHP variable I am using that variable in http-redirect but the problem is what happens when a song with duration 3minutes and 49 seconds is playing how to convert that into seconds. Because http-redirect works on seconds and not on minutes. If I use 3.49 * 60 that will make it 209.4 but actually 3 minutes and 49 seconds have 229 seconds.

Comment: What's the exact format of what the API gives you for the duration?

Comment: it give in hh:mm:ss like 3:49 or 5:15:36

Comment: You need to [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the colon but then count the result to see if there was an hour value or just minutes and seconds. Straightforward from there on.

Comment: 3 min 49 s is totally different from 3.49 min!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
<?php
// $length is the length of the song
$length_array = explode('.', $length);
$seconds = $length_array[0] * 60 + $length_array[1];
// ... redirect after $seconds ...
```

That cuts the string into 2 pieces, the first one is the amount of minutes (that are multiplied by 60 to get the amout of seconds) and the second one is the amount of seconds.

See **[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)** to learn more.

Hope this helps.